# Setup a http proxy for xulrunner application with authuntication

Tags: mozilla, xulrunner, squid, gecko, http-proxy

I was able to see my requests through proxy If I add this in pref.js

```
pref("network.proxy.http", "proxy.abc.org");
pref("network.proxy.http_port", 3128); 
pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
```

How to add authentication for such a kind of proxy.
Where to specify my username and password.

I am using a browser control in xul code, It is not prompting for the username and password.

Help is highly appreciated

Comment: Passwords are stored in `signons.sqlite` (database file used by the login manager). Copying it over from Firefox should work if no master password is defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.  I would like to know If I can write in pref.js or some other location or mechanism to do that. I am unable to make my app work because I crated a profile folder in defaults/ . But still even If I copy that file this approach is not working and not seems to be very useful. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this question since you first asked it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Spec: Proxy-Authorization and Authorization headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023636/http-spec-proxy-authorization-and-authorization-headers)