# HTTP Spec: Proxy-Authorization and Authorization headers

Tags: http, authentication, basic-authentication, specifications, proxy-authentication

So I'm trying to implement the following scenario:

- An application is protected by Basic Authentication. Let's say it is hosted on `app.com`
- An HTTP proxy, in front of the application, requires authentication as well. It is hosted on `proxy.com`

The user must therefore provide credentials for both the proxy and the application in the same request, thus he has different username/password pairs: one pair to authenticate himself against the application, and another username/password pair to authenticate himself against the proxy.

After reading the specs, I'm not really sure on how I should implement this. What I was thinking to do is:

1. The user makes an HTTP request to the proxy without any sort of authentication.
2. The proxy answers `407 Proxy Authentication Required` and returns a `Proxy-Authenticate` header in the format of: `"Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="proxy.com"`.
   **Question**: Is this `Proxy-Authenticate` header correctly set?
3. The client then retries the request with a `Proxy-Authorization` header, that is the Base64 representation of the proxy `username:password`.
4. This time the proxy authenticates the request, but then the application answers with a `401 Unauthorized` header. The user was authenticated by the proxy, but not by the application. The application adds a `WWW-Authenticate` header to the response like `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="app.com"`. **Question**: this header value is correct right?
5. The client retries again the request with both a `Proxy-Authorization` header, and a `Authorization` header valued with the Base64 representation of the app's `username:password`.
6. At this point, the proxy successfully authenticates the request, forwards the request to the application that authenticates the user as well. And the client finally gets a response back.

Is the whole workflow correct?

Comment: Well, thanks for having Proxy-* headers explained here, was looking for them. But did you solved your problem? Why the question is still open?

Comment: Since you just asked for a general validation of the approach I tried to add some additional color in my answer around other permutations of this setup. However, if you're asking this question because you tried what you described and encountered a specific error, please update the question to include that error; although I tried my best to validate what you posted, the real test would be simply to try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, that looks like a valid workflow for the situation you described, and those Authenticate headers seem to be in the correct format.

It's interesting to note that it's possible, albeit unlikely, for a given connection to involve multiple proxies that are chained together, and each one can itself require authentication. In this case, the client side of each intermediate proxy would itself get back a `407 Proxy Authentication Required` message and itself repeat the request with the `Proxy-Authorization` header; the `Proxy-Authenticate` and `Proxy-Authorization` headers are single-hop headers that do not get passed from one server to the next, but `WWW-Authenticate` and `Authorization` are end-to-end headers that are considered to be from the client to the final server, passed through verbatim by the intermediaries.

Since the `Basic` scheme sends the password in the clear (base64 is a reversible encoding) it is most commonly used over SSL. This scenario is implemented in a different fashion, because it is desirable to prevent the proxy from seeing the password sent to the final server:

- the client opens an SSL channel to the proxy to initiate the request, but instead of submitting a regular HTTP request it would submit [a special `CONNECT` request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_Tunneling) (still with a `Proxy-Authorization` header) to open a TCP tunnel to the remote server.
- The client then proceeds to create *another* SSL channel nested inside the first, over which it transfers the final HTTP message including the `Authorization` header.

In this scenario the proxy only knows the host and port the client connected to, not what was transmitted or received over the inner SSL channel. Further, the use of nested channels allows the client to "see" the SSL certificates of both the proxy and the server, allowing the identity of both to be authenticated.

Comment: I know I'm resurrecting this field of knowledge from you (being 2 years ago), but do you know if most modern browsers send proxy basic auth over SSL?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question, but: the browser will send basic auth credentials over the same channel as it sends requests, so if your proxy URL is https: then it will be in the SSL channel, but if your proxy URL is just http: then it will be in the clear.

Comment: (If I didn't understand your question it's probably best to start a new top-level question rather than trying to explain further here. There's room for more detail in a question than a comment.)