# Access AWS VPC elasticsearch nodes from Heroku

Tags: heroku, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

I have a VPC for elasticsearch nodes in AWS behind an internal load balancer. How can I access the nodes from a Heroku Ruby application.

I can't have the ES nodes as public facing.

Should I instead use a proxy to secure Elasticsearch and reach the proxy from the ruby app with some URL key? Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look at a proxy Authentication mechanism. I personally would recommend using something like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)

You can read more about its Authentication support here:

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Authentication

This is a another post that talks about a similar workflow to what you have:

[HTTP Spec: Proxy-Authorization and Authorization headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023636/http-spec-proxy-authorization-and-authorization-headers)

Comment: Thank you Rico, I did some research earlier and decided to use nginx. Appreciate the help. Voted up.