# In Httpful, how do I bypass authenticate network security appliance?

Tags: laravel, authentication, post, http-post, httpful

We have a Cisco security appliance at my office that forwards all outgoing requests to an ENVOY site and then routes out. While we have full permission to HTTP POST/GET to a certain website - this "firewall" still asks for authentication after every 5 minutes (through a standard authenticate).

So I have to authenticate manually using my domain/username and password (using a browser) and then my Laravel project works.

But if I forget to do it - Laravel throws me an error.

I tried everything to authenticate using the script.

Here's a sample of my httpful code from Laravel job:

```
            $responsePD = \Httpful\Request::post($urlPD)->sendTypes(\Httpful\Mime::UPLOAD)->body(array('stamp' => $stamp))
                        ->attach(array('fileName' => (public_path() . '\\' . $csvProjectDetails)))
                        ->followRedirects(true)->authenticateWithBasic('ntsupport\usrname', 'pw19580')->send();
```

As you can see, I'm using authenticateWithBasic - I tried all the authenticate methods in the httpful documentation - even trying to focus the redirect but it still won't authenticate manually.

Comment: "IT" asks for authentication: WHAT does?

Comment: The security device - think of it as a firewall.

Comment: Did you try to include the `Proxy-Authorization` header? See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10023636/18044